# Writing Python output to either screen or filename

Tags: python, class, logging

I am writing some code that will output a log to either the screen, or a file, but not both.
I thought the easiest way to do this would be to write a class:

```
class WriteLog:
    "write to screen or to file"

    def __init__(self, stdout, filename):
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.logfile = file(filename, 'a')

    def write(self, text):
        self.stdout.write(text)
        self.logfile.write(text)

    def close(self):
        self.stdout.close()
        self.logfile.close()
```

And then call it something like this:

```
output = WriteLog(sys.stdout, 'log.txt')
```

However, I'm not sure how to allow for switching between the two, i.e. there should be an option within the class that will set `WriteLog` to either use stdout, or `filename`. Once that option has been set I just use `WriteLog` without any need for `if` statements etc.

Any ideas?  Most of the solutions I see online are trying to output to both simultaneously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? It uses the symbolic name `'stdout'` or `'stderr`' in the constructor, or a real filename. The usage of `if` is limited to the constructor. By the way, I think you're trying to prematurely optimize (which is the root of all evil): you're trying to save time on `if`'s while in real life, the program will spend much more time in file I/O; making the potential waste on your `if`'s negligible.

```
import sys

class WriteLog:

    def __init__(self, output):
        self.output = output
        if output == 'stdout':
            self.logfile = sys.stdout
        elif output == 'stderr':
            self.logfile = sys.stderr
        else:
            self.logfile = open(output, 'a')

    def write(self, text):
        self.logfile.write(text)

    def close(self):
        if self.output != 'stdout' and self.output != 'stderr':
            self.logfile.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = WriteLog('stdout')
    a.write('This goes to stdout\n')
    b = WriteLog('stderr')
    b.write('This goes to stderr\n')
    c = WriteLog('/tmp/logfile')
    c.write('This goes to /tmp/logfile\n')
```

Comment: That worked nicely!  Thank you.  I'll try and embrace the `if` statements ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in it, but try to use the [logging library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), and maybe you can have logger with 2 handlers, one for file and one for stream and then add/remove handlers dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I like the suggestion about using the logging library. But if you want to hack out something yourself, maybe passing in the file handle is worth considering.

```
import sys

class WriteLog:
    "write to screen or to file"

    def __init__(self, output):
        self.output = output

    def write(self, text):
        self.output.write(text)

    def close(self):
        self.output.close()

logger = WriteLog(file('c:/temp/log.txt','a' ))
logger.write("I write to the log file.\n")
logger.close()

sysout = WriteLog(sys.stdout)
sysout.write("I write to the screen.\n")
```

Comment: Thanks.  Ended up going with Karel's slightly more extensive implementation but this was what I was looking for.  Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) library to do something similar to this. The following function will set up a logging object at the `INFO` level.

```
def setup_logging(file_name, log_to_file=False, log_to_console=False ):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Create Console handler
    if log_to_file:
        console_log = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(name)-12s - %(message)s')
        console_log.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(console_log)

    # Log file
    if log_to_console:
        file_log = logging.FileHandler('%s.log' % (file_name), 'a', encoding='UTF-8')
        file_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(name)-12s - %(message)s')
        file_log.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_log)

    return logger
```

You pass it the name of your log, and where you wish to log (either to the file, the console or both). Then you can utilize this function in your code block like this:

```
logger = setup_logging("mylog.log", log_to_file=True, log_to_console=False)
logger.info('Message')
```

This example will log to a file named `mylog.log` (in the current directory) and have output like this:

```
2014-11-05 17:20:29,933 - INFO     - root         - Message
```

This function has areas for improvement (if you wish to add more functionality). Right now it logs to both the console and file at log level `INFO` on the `.setLevel(logging.INFO)` lines. This could be set dynamically if you wish.

Additionally, as it is now, you can easily add standard logging lines (`logger.debug('Message')`, `logger.critcal('DANGER!')`) without modifying a class. In these examples, the debug messages won't print (because it is set to `INFO`) and the critical ones will.

Comment: Thank you Andy.  I knew about the `logging` library but in this case, wanted to try and roll my own.  Appreciate your detailed example!